# Finding the largest submatrix contain only one zero and 1's in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I need to find a submatrix that only contain a 0,but others are 1.
Here's an example:

```
5*4 matrix
1 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 1
```

And the answer will be

```
3*3
1 0 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

I tried to use other similar questions' methods.But so far I can't figure out how to calculate it without using brutal solution.

Comment: What are the "similar question's methods" ? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you have any constraint about the submatrix size and shape? I guess it should be a square matrix, but any size is fine or has to be, for example, the biggest one?

Comment: Sorry for not describle the question clearly.My goal is find the largest square which contain one 0 and others are all 1s.As what I try now,I trying to use the largest submatrix of all 1's method to calculate my question.I don't know if it will work or not.I have a chart on my computer,I can post it as soon as I get to my computer.

Comment: So question explicity asks for largest "square" matrix, or answer could be an arbitrary sized rectangle matrix?

Comment: What does "large" mean in your problem ? The surface in number of elements ?

Comment: I want to find square first,but if it's possible,I want to find arbitrary sized rectangle matrix too.If there is any document that discussing this topic,please give me a link.I couldn't find people asking the samequestion as mine.

Comment: I think problem is a slightly changed version of "submatrix with maximum sum". You should study that problem and make appropriate modifications to adapt that solution into your problem. Its solved with Kadane's algorithm.

Comment: unlut,thank you for your advice,this helps me a lot.